# List duplicate names of .png file name to text file by skipping hash (#)

Tags: c#, file-io, duplicates, filenames

I am trying to check how can I check all the file names that have the same names and wanted to group those similar file names with folder path and export them to a text file.

So far I have written the following codes which will allow me to find # inside every .png file name and successfully add the number after the #. But I am unable to check for duplicate names by skipping the # and number after that.

All of my file names are in .png format.

I have like more than 100 sub folders and every folder got around more than 2 files upto 25 files of .png.

File naming styles:

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderDlg.SelectedPath = "C:\\Users\\demo\\Documents\\process\\";
            if (folderDlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Has different framework dependend implementations 
            // in order to handle unauthorized access to subfolders
            RenameAllPngFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);
        }
        private void RenameAllPngFiles(string directoryPath)
        {
            RenameCurrentPng(directoryPath);
            foreach (var item in GetDirectoryInfos(directoryPath))
            {
                RenameCurrentPng(item.FullName);
            }
        }

        private void RenameCurrentPng(string directoryPath)
        {
            int fileNameSuffixCounter = 1;
            foreach (string originalFullFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png"))
            {
                string ShortFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFullFileName);
                if (!ShortFileName.Contains("#"))
                {
                    // The new file name without path
                    var newFileName = $"{ShortFileName}#{fileNameSuffixCounter++}{System.IO.Path.GetExtension(originalFullFileName)}";
                    FileSystem.RenameFile(originalFullFileName, newFileName);
                }
            }
        }

        private DirectoryInfo[] GetDirectoryInfos(string directoryPath)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
            DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories("*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            return directories;
    }
```

Comment: Really hard to tell what you're asking. It sounds like you have eg files like `c:\img\monday\some#1.png c:\img\tuesday\some#1.png c:\img\wednesday\some#1.png` and you want to make the file names unique across all subfolders eg `c:\img\monday\some#1.png c:\img\tuesday\some#2.png c:\img\wednesday\some#3.png` - is it right? If it's not right, can you edit your question so your problem is presented similarly; say what you have got/where you are, and what you what to have/where you want to be at the end of the process?

Comment: @CaiusJard hey thanks for reply. I want to catch the duplicate names across all folder. But in my file name i got xxx#1.png. I want to exclude this # and number when looking for duplicate file names and then group and list them/processs the list of names to text file

Answer (score 0):

This will group up files by fragment of name before # and suggest new names by adding a unique number across all subfolders

```
    var fs = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\temp\\a", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    var changes = fs
        .GroupBy(f => Path.GetFileName(f).Split('#', 2)[0],
          (k, g) => g.Select((f, i) => new
          {
              OldPath = f,
              NewPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(f), $"{k}#{i}{Path.GetExtension(f)}")
          })
        );
```

So what does it do?

- Enumerates all files in all directories into `fs`
- Group `fs` by `filename.Split('#', 2)[0]` which means "split on #, return at most 2 substrings because we only need the first, take the first as the thing to group on"
- This results in e.g. a grouping of all the different `a#xx.txt` into one list. The second argument to GroupBy is like running a select on the result of the grouping (an "array" of all file paths with names that start with `a`)

  - `k` is the key, i.e. the `a` in `a#1.txt` or `b` in `'b#1.txt`.
  - `g` is the group(array) of the full file paths
- This means we can run a `Select` on `g` and use the overload of `Select((item, index_of_item)`

  - `f` is the item i.e. the full path,
  - `i` is the index in the "array" i.e. a unique number for that file name.
- Using this we will make a new object that is

  - `OldPath` of the original full path `f`, and
  - `NewPath` which is "the directory of `f`, plus the key of the group which is everything before the first #, plus an #, plus the unique number `i`, plus the extension of `f`

I suppose then, if you want to run some renames, it would be handy to have them as a list of old/new name pairs. There's something else it might be wise to do too; have a temporary, guaranteed unique filename that we move it to first:

```
var flatListWithTempName = changes.SelectMany(x => x, x =>
  new { 
    x.OldPath,
    x.NewPath, 
    TempPath = x.OldPath + Guid.NewGuid()
  }
).ToArray();

foreach(var change in flatListWithTempName){
  File.Move(change.OldPath, change.TempPath);
}

foreach(var change in flatListWithTempName){
  File.Move(change.TempPath, change.NewPath);
}
```

SelectMany will unwrap one level of nest. The second argument reshapes the Old/New to have a temp path too with a new guid. Why do this?

Well, suppose for some reason one of your renames was `a#1.txt -> a#10.txt` but the folder already contained `a#10.txt`, you'd get an issue. By tripping through a unique filename you avoid any collisions. By adding a guid onto the name we make it unique, and easy to undo the guid on the end (trim off the last 36 chars) if the program crashed leaving the job half done

---

Using slightly longer variable names if it helps you:

```
var fullPathsOfAllFiles = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\temp\\a", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var changes = fullPathsOfAllFiles 
        .GroupBy(fullPathOfOneFile => Path.GetFileName(fullPathOfOneFile).Split('#', 2)[0],
          (partialNameBeforeHash, fullPathsWithThatPartial) => arrayOfFullPathsWithThatPartial.Select((fullPath, arrayIndex) => new
          {
              OldPath = fullPath,
              NewPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath), $"{partialNameBeforeHash}#{arrayIndex}{Path.GetExtension(fullPath)}")
          })
        );
```

I say "array", because it acts like one for these purposes, but it's actually an enumerable

---

Here's a file structure with duplicated names:

[image]

Here's the contents of the group result. You can see the NewPath have all renumbered files in, starting from 0 and all file names are unique:

[image]